Access .SQL files located in another project
I have 2 projects within a single solution:
-- Solution
-- -- ProjectOne
-- -- -- Data
-- -- -- -- CreateTable.sql
-- -- ProjectOne.Test
-- -- -- DatabaseFixture.cs

My goal is to spin up an in-memory SQLite database in DatabaseFixture.cs and run the .SQL files. What is a reliable way to access these .SQL files given that they are in another project? Do they need a build action?

The unit test project have access to tested assembly codebase and resources. To run sql-files they needs to be available, e.g. put into resources. What do you want to test? Public methods or sql-files?

Intent is to test my data access methods (public methods). These are located inside of the ProjectOne. They do not rely on the .SQL files. However, I may make use of them in other areas within that project which is why they are located there rather than within the Test project

The .sql is a file and you need to be able to access the path/file from both projects.  Put the file in a location that is in a common folder than both project have access.  Usually you create a shared folder on a network drive so any user can access the file from any machine.
